# User folder names with a blank causes failure for anaconda

Tags: tensorflow, keras, anaconda, python-3.5

[A screen shot of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Ngii.jpg)

I have been trying to install Keras for about a week now. I installed Anaconda and then Tensorflow with Python3.5 and Jupyter. When I start up with the Anaconda3 prompt it always gives me the message 
   `>was unexpected at this time`
   `C:\Users\Ray Van>@IF NOT "==" @chcp > NUL`
   `C:\Users\Ray Van>`
I used to be able to just say
Jupyter Notebook but it doesn't like this
Also I want to say activate tensorflow and then say jupyter notebook and then run a Python program with Keras (for Neural networks) but no matter what I tried, nothing works. I read somewhere that having the blank in the name \Ray Van] can be a problem but I didn't set that up. Somehow it was just set up by Windows 10 and from reading various posts, it seem very difficult to change without risking having to install Windows10 again. Various places say that it is very easy to install Keras, but I have found the opposite after trying several days for 3 hours at a time. But I am not good at installing things like this and don't really understand how all the things are connected. Maybe I have to start over and install Anaconda and then tensorflow and then from within the tensorflow environment install Keras and Jupyter. I know the pip command or the conda command are used for this but I don't really understand that either. So a total newbie who just wants to run some Python programs for my Neural Network research using Keras.

Comment: Try to exchange each ` ` by `\ ` in your path.